# Gatling - changed fields in simulation.log

Tags: gatling

Previously simulation log had 4 long values ([old gatling documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/1.5.6/general_information/faq.html#q-what-s-the-meaning-of-the-4-longs-in-simulation-log-file)):

> ```
> 1. first byte sent timestamp
> 2. last byte sent timestamp
> 3. first byte received timestamp
> 4. last byte received timestamp
> ```

What had been calculated to:

> ```
> response time (in ms) = 4 - 1
> latency (in ms) = 3 - 2
> ```

Currently I see only two values:

> REQUEST   Scenario    1       case    1487348824858   1487348825029   OK

Those are only values nb.1 and nb.4 from first example?
And are defined here https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/stats/writer/LeakReporterDataWriter.scala#L67?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a response indirectly here [Gatling Executor for Taurus v1.9.5](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/blob/1.9.5/site/dat/docs/Gatling.md) (disappeared with [Gatling Executor for Taurus v1.9.6](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/blob/1.9.6/site/dat/docs/Gatling.md)).

By default it uses Gatling 2.1.7 because:

> Taurus works with Gatling 2.2.0. However, with Gatling 2.2.0 it's not possible to extract such network stats as latency and connection time, as Gatling removed them from report data. Because of that, Taurus installs Gatling 2.1.7 by default.

By analysing the code of this [executor](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/blob/master/bzt/modules/gatling.py), there are two data extrator, one for [gatling 2.1](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/blob/1.9.6/bzt/modules/gatling.py#L550), another for [gatling 2.2](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/blob/1.9.6/bzt/modules/gatling.py#L592).